# How do you describe the rain coming from the oblique angle in idiomatic way?

Tags: word-request

What is non-scientific way of describing the rain fall that does not come down in the right angle?

I know in scientific way that angle is called oblique angle, but I am not sure if that's the way that it is said in everyday spoken English. I mean I don't want my sentence to sound like a text book! Not very formal not informal!

Comment: 'The rain slanted down' is common enough to almost be a cliché.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, that's an answer though! :)

Comment: A *right angle* is 90° (or 270°)  degrees. Normally rain does **not** come down at a 90° angle. (There would have to be an extremely powerful and unusual wind for that.) Instead, it comes down at a 180° (or 0°, depending on how you look at it) angle. If it fell at a 90° angle, it would be falling *sideways*. *Oblique* is somewhere in between 90° (horizontal) and 180° (vertical).

Comment: @JasonBassford 90° is defined as being perpendicular to a given plane. The plane is this case is the ground, so 0° would run parallel to the ground and 90° would be straight down. (Although you could make the argument that 90° would, in fact, be up, and 270° would be down.)

Comment: @WillRoss1 Since the question is describing the motion of *rain*, I find it odd that you would define the referential plane as the *ground* instead. The normal motion of rain would be a 0° deviation from the typical path that gravity pulls it in; in other words its path from the clouds to the ground.

Comment: @WillRoss1 Using the ground as the reference would be particularly problematic if it weren't a flat surface. What if the "ground" itself were a hill or some other surface that were not horizontal with respect to the normal direction of an object under gravity's influence? If the ground itself is on an incline, any discussion of rain's normal direction of travel would be skewed.

Comment: @WillRoss1 Generally, you would use a plumb line or level. Straight up is 0°.

Comment: @JasonBassford I see your point, everything is relative in this world, even sometimes in classic physics:) It is just a matter of convention and agreement. Have a nice day!